# Is it possible to learn which function to fit a regression with?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I need help with modeling data that sometimes has non-linear relationships.

I am building a software system that involves modeling cpu responses to application load. ie learn the function $\text{load} = f(\text{cpu})$.

Analyzing the data, I have found that CPU responses vary widely in their underlying relationship to application load across different applications. I have observed the following relationships:

- CPU is linear and can be modeled with a polynomial (most common case)
- CPU is logorithmic in relationship to load
- CPU has a root relationship with load (similar to the above)
- CPU is exponential, naturally or otherwise

*Note:* Its important to note these are always consistent per application, but may change if the underlying code changes.

I am currently using linear regression and I am able to learn the best degree of the polynomial for the model through optimization. But I am stuck on what to do for the non-linear cases (besides simply trying them and taking RMSE).

Is there a simple way to determine which functional form is best for the regression?

For context, I have the following constraints:

- **The model must be able to extrapolate accurately.** This is key as the system involves load projections. This is what makes the functional form important.
- I am using Golang, so I prefer simplest implementations possible due to immature code ecosystem. (Ie. I am aware I could approach this with a bayesian optimization solution over various models, implementing that would be too time consuming due to the limits Golang scientific ecosystem).
- I am learning a new model for each application every few minutes, so i'd like performant options if possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "*extrapolate accurately*"... That is a bit of a tall order. More seriously, I think your best course of action is to look into getting correct error metrics (RMSE, MAE) because from what you describe it seem you are currently looking into in-sample errors that are known not to generalse well. Have you looked into bootstrapping your estimates?

Comment: Generally I think yes there is room here for, what i think of as filtering, to get rid of in-sample errors as you say. I actually was thinking i'd have to do something much fancier than bootstrap but I will try that for in-sample errors.

However -  I can say with 100% confidence that the load to CPU usage does vary as I outlined above because the code executed is using algorithmns that have those signatures!